# Issue using Zend Framework on NetBeans

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans

I am learning about Zend Framework, I want to use NetBeans to start, but when I try to do this on NB: Tools -> Options -> PHP -> Zend -> Click on '*Register Provider*' the next error appear on output window:

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(NetBeansCommandsProvider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'NetBeansCommandsProvider.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php:/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
```

What can I do to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 2):

I could go one step further by adding the right path for **NetBeansCommandsProvider.php**. 
Just replace the **.zf.ini** content with:

```
php.include_path = "/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/home/username/.netbeans/6.9/zend/"
```

and **replace username** with your username.

Comment: Thanks. The part with `/home/username/.netbeans/...` worked for me. As Vitex pointed, this path can be also the `/usr/local/netbeans-7.0/php/zend` folder - it also contains the `NetBeansCommandsProvider.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

```
vitex@HuP:~$ export  ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND=/usr/local/netbeans-7.0/php/zend/
vitex@HuP:~$ zf enable config.provider NetBeansCommandsProvider
Provider/Manifest 'NetBeansCommandsProvider' was enabled for usage with Zend Tool.
```

Comment: On Windows (netbeans 7.1), instead of the first command, you gotta use: `SET ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1\php\zend`

Answer (score 1):

If you use an version of Zend Framework 1.10.5+ than check your **.zf.ini** 
located in your Home directory.

Change

```
php.includepath to php.include_path
```

there is an bug in the later versions if zf

Comment: I already did that... the problem persists: http://paste.ubuntu.com/495925/ Thanks for your help